# WSO2 API Manager health check

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager

I have the WSO2 API manager set up with the four components on different VM's. What I need to do is check the health of the components. Is there a url I can hit with each component to make sure it is running? I don't want to do a full API call as I don't want to test the whole flow just a specific VM so I know if I need to restart that VM.

I could do a port check but I am not sure if that is really checking the status properly.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps you could hit login API/s of API Manager's published API's(https://docs.wso2.com/display/AM190/Published+APIs) and examine the HTTP response code:

Publisher Login API:  https://docs.wso2.com/display/AM190/Publisher+APIs

```
curl -X POST -c cookies http://(publisherIP):9763/publisher/site/blocks/user/login/ajax/login.jag -d 'action=login&username=admin&password=admin'
```

Store Login API: https://docs.wso2.com/display/AM190/Store+APIs

```
curl -X POST -c cookies http://(storeIP):9763/store/site/blocks/user/login/ajax/login.jag -d 'action=login&username=admin&password=admin'
```

Gateway

```
https://docs.wso2.com/display/AM190/WSO2+Admin+Services
```

Key manager is a bit trickier , try getting an access token through the API gateway token API and see what it returns. The gateway will call the key manager:

```
curl -k -d "grant_type=password&username=<username>&password=<password>" -H "Authorization: Basic SVpzSWk2SERiQjVlOFZLZFpBblVpX2ZaM2Y4YTpHbTBiSjZvV1Y4ZkM1T1FMTGxDNmpzbEFDVzhh, Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded" https://(gatewayIP):8243/token
```